# TTF_OpenFont returns "library not initialized" error

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-ttf

I try to open a font via the `SDL_OpenFont()` function, but it returns `nullptr` and `TTF_GetError()` returns "Library not initialized".

`SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)` and `TTF_Init()` both return 0.

```
if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
    std::cout << "Couldn't initialize SDL: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

if(TTF_Init() < 0) {
    std::cout << "Couldn't initialize TTF lib: " << TTF_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont("DroidSans.ttf", 25);
if(!font) {
    std::cout << "Can't open font: " << TTF_GetError() << std::endl;
}
```

This is the output:

> Can't open font: Library not initialized

This is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(proj)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${proj_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2TTF REQUIRED SDL_ttf >= 2.0.0)

set(SOURCES main.cpp)

add_executable(proj ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(proj ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2TTF_LIBRARIES})
```

What's wrong?

Comment: We need a [mcve].

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thank you for your remark. I added sample of code.

Comment: I find it hard to believe since "library not initialized" error emited only when TTF_Init failed or wasn't called at all, which contradicts with code in question. What is your full code?

Comment: OS?  Compiler?  Using self-built SDL2 & SDL_ttf or pre-built binaries?   If binaries, which?